# How to access 2d array to enter a grade for a student? C#

Tags: c#, arrays

I'm trying to write to the console the name of a student from a 2d array,
and then read the grade value into the correct place inside the 2d array.
Each element in the array has a student name and grade.
Can anyone help me clarify this, I feel like I'm on the verge of a mental breakthrough if this can work.

```
static void AskNameForGrade()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < nameAndGradeArray.GetLength(0); i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Please enter grade for {nameAndGradeArray[i]}");

                for (int j = 0; j < nameArray.GetLength(1); j++)
                { 
                    string stringGrade = Console.ReadLine();
                    int.TryParse(stringGrade, out grade);
                    //read in grade to array match name shown
                }


            }
        }
```

Comment: please add the structure of the array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A multi-dimensional array must be of the same type I'd recommend using a Dictionary, you have a key and a value, where the value e.g. grade would belong to the name. if you use a dictionary this code should work

```
string[] names = new string[]{"Adam", "Brittany"};
Dictionary<string, int> nameAndGrades = new Dictionary<string, int>();
for (int i = 0; i < names.GetLength(0); i++)
{
    int grade = 0;
    while(true)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Please enter grade for {names[i]}");
        if(int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out grade))
        {   
            nameAndGrades.Add(names[i], grade);
            break;
        }
    }
}

foreach (var vp in nameAndGrades)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{vp.Key} : {vp.Value}");
}
```

you can see it in action with this [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/YyLvD4)

Answer (score 1):

You said your array is 2D and then you try access it with a single dimension with `nameAndGradeArray[i]` - this won't work

You don't need/shouldn't have a loop to store the grade- the loop starts from 0 so probably overwrites the name (assuming namearray is a typo) in doing so and then asks for another grade

Assuming you have an nameAndGradeArray that is e.g. `string[10,2]` you'd have one loop that runs from 0 to `GetLenth(0)-1` (i.e. 9) and prints the name it finds in `[i,0]`, then asks for a grade and stores the grade with `nameAndGradeArray[i,1] = stringGrade;`

nameAndGradeArray is (probably) a 2D string array; you can't put an int into it. If you're using TryParse to check they entered a number it makes sense, but maybe leave that bit of complexity out for now and just ask the grade and store it. Also don't need the namearray (if that's not a typo) if the name is already in the first dimension of the nameAndGrade

This is likely an academic exercise so I'll avoid making deeper recommendations but you'll probably not used N dimensional arrays so much in future because they aren't very useful. One day you'll model this as a class that has a string name and a number grade, and it'll be in a flexible collection like a List..